# Why auto status of user for badges is not shown?

Tags: feature-request, badges

In the [Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) screen currently the format is

[image: current badges image]

Now, my question is why is it not shown that:

- How much more points, I need for particular badge
- How much I progress on it
- ...etc,

Or why does it not have a particular page for this ?

Below I am posting an image, in case you are not clear about my question.

[image: proposed badges image]

Comment: Performance maybe?

Comment: They are maintaining the record for it, why they don't show it.

Comment: No, they are not maintaining the record for it, it is calculated on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

It has particular page for this, go to your activity page and find pagelet where your badges are shown like this, click on the settings glyphicon and it will show your status towards your badges.

[image]

Comment: I guess OP knows that, but the FR is to show it in the badge list.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I also thought that, but keeping in mind that op is only two month old to SE and by his question i don't think he is concerning about showing it on badge list if op clears that i will delete this post.